# Have I correctly used comma in the following sentences

Tags: punctuation

Have I correctly used comma in the following sentences?

1. However, he soon realized he was short of money, even though he had sold his car to pay his debts.
2. He was sent to Court, and the court ordered imprisonment up to six months.
3. Tomorrow, we will look again into your case.
4. The judge pronounced the new sentence by saying, “The Court had
   decided to cancel the sentence. Though, the father will be under
   surveillance.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would re-write two of them:

(2) He was sent to the court, which ordered imprisonment (for) up to six months.

(4) The judge pronounced the new sentence:

“The court has decided to cancel the sentence.
       However, the father will be (kept) under surveillance.”

Changes recommended:

*court*, lower case; its repetition is avoided by the presence of the relative pronoun, "which"

*pronounced* the new sentence conveys it; "had decided" (past perfect) isn't the right tense here and hence *has decided* (present perfect) is recommended; *However* fits better than "though".

Answer (score 2):

Commas often do no harm when put in places where they're not really needed.  I think your choices are, in general, good. In #4 we could do without one after "though" and could use one after "sentence".

Three out of four isn't bad.  You should change your name to NotMrStupid.